# Reason for vertical gap between bootstrap grid DIVs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

*I am new to Bootstrap.*

I have a 4 div grid on my website (http://www.prynk.com/developer/) with  class="col-md-6 col-lg-3".

Ideally I want a 2x2 grid on medium resolution screens and 4x1 grid on large.

The issue I'm having is that the columns don't align correctly in the Y direction.

Look at http://www.prynk.com/developer/ with browser window ~1200px (or just resize until you see two columns). At this point, there is a large gap between grid box 3 and 4; can someone explain WHY this is happening?

My code:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img />
        <div class="caption center-text">
            <h3 class="ptsans">Coming soon!</h3>
            <p>blah blah.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your columns all have a different height since they are stretching to accommodate the content of their children. Try adding the following to your CSS file:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-3 {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-6 {
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

This just defines the heights for the columns based on the media queries that `.col-md` and `.col-lg` represent. The actual height value is not important, as long as it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first `div` tag is a lot longer than `div` number two. Here you can see how the first one is preventing the third one from taking the space below:

[image: []

I used to solve this by using the server-side language to insert a clearfix element thus aligning my boxes, but I see that there are a lot better techniques using CSS only. You should be able to fix this with `display: flex` and `flex-wrap` - [this tutorials](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback) explains the situation, hope it helps you out.

Comment: I really like that grid! Although that didn't work for me immediately, I'll be switching over to it. Thanks!